# Unity display my generic list in the editor

Tags: unity, c#

I have the following class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class BaseBehaviour<T> : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public List<BaseAction<T>> Actions;
    protected int currentIndex = 0;
    public bool OptOut = false;
    public Intelligence.Intelligence Intelligence;
    public T BaseAiContext;
    public List<BaseConsideration> Considerations;
    
    public Dictionary<string, object> CacheValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public abstract void UpdateBehaviour();

    public bool IsDone()
    {
        if (currentIndex > Actions.Count || OptOut)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public abstract float GetScore();
}
```

Then i have an implementation of this class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class AttackTargetBehaviour : BaseBehaviour<ExampleAI>
{
    public override void UpdateBehaviour()
    {
        Actions[0].Execute(this);
    }

    public override float GetScore()
    {
        float currentScore = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Actions.Count; i++)
        {
            float score = 0; // Actions[i].GetScore(this);
            if (score <= 0.0f)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                currentScore *= score;
            }
        }

        return currentScore;
    }
}
```

However here the list doesn't show in the inspector window which ultimately means i can't add my `scriptableobject` actions.

Can anyone tell me how i can display such as list in the `Unity` inspector?

For reference my action looks like this:

```
    [System.Serializable]
public abstract class BaseAction<TContext> : ScriptableObject, IAction
{
```

And the implementation of this class is:

```
    [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Move to Target", menuName = "AnAppGames/AI/Example/Actions/MoveToTargetAction")]

public class MoveToTargetAction : BaseAction<ExampleAI>
{
    public override void Execute(BaseBehaviour<ExampleAI> context)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void OnUpdate(BaseBehaviour<ExampleAI> context)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void OnStop(BaseBehaviour<ExampleAI> context)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: What Unity version are you using? 2020 has better generic support than 2019, so that may be a factor.

Comment: I am using 2019 I will try and update to 2020

Answer (score 1):

Unity 2020 can handle more instances of generic types without extra steps. So something like this will display in the editor out of the box:

```
public UnityEvent<int> myEvent;
```

In Unity 2019 or earlier, you can sometimes work around the restrictions by giving a concrete name to the generic variant you want to use. Like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class EventWithIntegerArgument : UnityEvent<int> {}
public EventWithIntegerArgument myEvent;
```

So for your example, you may be able to take:

```
public abstract class BaseBehaviour<T> : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public List<BaseAction<T>> Actions;
```

And make it...

```
public abstract class BaseBehaviour<T> : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class TypeSpecificAction : BaseAction<T> {}

    [SerializeField]
    public List<TypeSpecificAction> Actions;
```

Here, each concrete instantiation of `BaseBehaviour<T>` for a different type `T` will also create its own nested `TypeSpecificAction` type based on that T. Since it's a specific named type, not a generic, it *should* work with Unity's serializer. But I have not tested this specific case.